# PHP Remove columns from csv

Tags: php, csv

I need to remove some columns and the first row from a csv and put the result in a new csv file.
I tried already with some sugesstions found here on stack, but none of them will work for me.
My csv has 9 columns but i only need 5 of them. 
The best found solution here to remove the columns seems to be the one i will post below, but i only get commas in the result file and some where some data. 
The data in my csv are spararted with ';' 
I hope any one can help me.

Here is the code i played with:

```
<?php
 $input = 'gesamtbestand.csv';
 $output = 'mw-stock.csv';

 if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {
$oh = fopen($output, 'w');

while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
    // this is where you build your new row
    $outputData = array($data[1], $data[2], $data[4], $data[5], $data[8]);
    fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
}

fclose($ih);
fclose($oh);
}
```

Comment: Third parameter of fgetcsv is a `delimiter`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: Explain __what__?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default delimiter for fgetcsv is , as you can see in php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

If your csv file uses ; for delimiter then you should change the line

```
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
```

to

```
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih, 0, ";"))) {
```

The default enclosure is "

if you don't use an enclosure in your data then you should change the line to

```
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih, 0, ";", ""))) {
```

As for excluding the first entry of the csv file you can do this

```
$i=0;
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
    // this is where you build your new row
    if ($i!=0){
        $outputData = array($data[1], $data[2], $data[4], $data[5], $data[8]);
        fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
    }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. This was really a great help. It works now.
Thank you so much. :)

Comment: BTW. Is there also a way to remove also the first row of the new file?

Comment: You want the first row of the output file to be empty? Or you want to exclude the first line of the input file?

Comment: I want to exclude the first row completely. Because after i removed the columns the content of the new csv will be added to another csv.
It works allready thanks to you and it's just a cosmetic thing. :)

Comment: i think we have a misunderstanding with rows and columns :) I think what u mean is that if one line of your csv is "param1;param2;param3;param4" you want to keep only "param2:param3:param4" of lines 1,2,4,5,8 right?

Comment: sorry for my late response. 
remove some columns is what i wanted.so everything is fine.
But i combine the csv with another, what means that the content from the csv from where i removed the colums will be added on the end of the other file.
both files have column names like 'id', 'stock' etc.
so i thought it may be also possible to remove that first line of the csv from where i have deleted the not needed columns.
as i say it is not verry important but just a cosmetic thing for me. :)

Comment: You can set a variable before the while statement to 0. Example $i=0; and include the fputcsv command in an if ($i!=0) and then increase $i before closing while. I will update my answer to show that better

Comment: Ah. Thanks again. Works perfect for me. You saved my day. :)